# I'm looking for a library that will allow Django users to OAuth authenticate to an API and Django to access their data

Tags: django

I've done some Googling but I can't find the right Django library to use. Here's the scenario:

My Django website has muiltiple users who register and log in using the built in Django user management features. I now want the website to access these users data from a third party site via that site's REST API. The third party site API requires the users authenticate via OAuth2.

1. User registers on my website and logs in
2. User follows link on my site, to give my site access their data stored on third party website, via REST API
3. User is forwarded to the third party website where they agree to give my website access and are sent back as per OAuth pattern.
4. My website should then be able to access the users data on the third party site, which it will access once per day, at night, to download the latest data.
5. Access needs to be maintained indefinitely (token needs to refresh?), so that their data is accessible to my site, until the user chooses to disable the feature.

Answer (score 0):

We at Pathfix call this the OAuth authorization proxy/server. Pathfix is built for this exact use case. You can use the button generated by Pathfix to initiate authorization and then pass the API calls via our universal endpoint.

Pathfix was built out of this exact need. Other ways of achieving this is to download passport.js/ pizzly or sdk for different providers and maintain the code with your build. And let us not forget keeping up with updates to OAuth releases.